# How to use ejb in webapplication

Tags: java, jboss, ejb-3.0

I want to call ejb from servlet via remote interface. Maybe it is a RTFM question but i cannot find solution via Google or documentation. What configuration steps I need to do than ejb be accessible for webapps

I use Jboss 4.2, Java 1.6

Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this in your servlet:

```
@EJB
private YourEJBRemoteInterface remoteService;
```

And you will have your service injected. (you may need to set the `name` of the `@EJB` annotation)

Another way is to use JNDI lookup, but this is obsolete.

Update: Since your JBoss version seems obsolete as well, the JNDI lookup is the way to go. int your servlet `init(..)` method lookup the EJB through JNDI (using `InitialContext`),  and set them as fields, as if dependency-injection has been performed.

Comment: According to this link http://www.coderanch.com/t/163667/java-EJB-SCBCD/certification/EJB-annotation-servlet-JBoss Jboss does not support EJB injection in Servlet

Comment: As I understand see i have asked question incorrect: I need solution how to configure webapp that way that servlets can use EJB. I have edited my question.